# Python Jupiter Notebook filtering data with values from the same column

Tags: python, csv

Could someone tell me how I can edit the final parameter of this line to get the right data?

The current line will show me all data that follows the current criteria:

**>=** may 2010 & **<=** dec 2010 & **==** orange beach

This works fine but I was wondering how I get results for:

**>=** may 2010 & **<=** dec 2010 **==** orange beach, orange beach 2, orange beach 3, orange beach 4

This is my code line:

```
df1 = df[(df['date_start'] >='2010-05-01 00:00:00') & (df['date_start'] <= '2010-12-31 00:00:00')  & (df['location_description'] == 'Orange Beach, AL')
```

I need to pull multiple values from the same location_description column agaist the 2 values from the data_start column

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df['location_description'].isin(['Orange Beach 1', 'orange beach 2'])`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isin` keyword:

```
df1 = df[(df['date_start'] >='2010-05-01 00:00:00') & (df['date_start'] <= '2010-12-31 00:00:00')  & (df.location_description.isin(['Orange Beach','Orange Beach 1']))
```